# Get heading from RotationMatrix in iOS

Tags: ios, compass-geolocation, rotational-matrices, heading, cmmotionmanager

I receive the RotationMatrix from my CMMotionManager and want to calculate my phone's heading from it, e.g. 38 degrees North (and avoid CLLocationManager), in order to make a more accurate compass:

```
 [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {

 CMRotationMatrix rm = deviceMotion.attitude.rotationMatrix;

 // Get the heading.
 motionHeading = M_PI + atan2(rm.m22, rm.m12);
 motionHeading = motionHeading*180/M_PI;
```

However this only works when the phone is flat on the table. What should i use as formula to allow for all phone's positions in my hand, being in landscape mode, and the device looking above or under the horizon ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917016/corelocation-heading-base-on-back-camera-augmented-reality) that works pretty well in terms of movement stability.