# Using CoreMotion / CoreLocation to compute north heading from back of phone

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, heading, azimuth

I want to get the azimuth from the back of the phone (-Z axis) for an augmented reality app. My application only runs in Landscape Right. Testing this on iPhone 5S.

Currently, I'm using the following approach:
[CoreLocation heading base on back camera (Augmented reality)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917016/corelocation-heading-base-on-back-camera-augmented-reality)

I have 2 problems with this approach:

1. If I'm pointing the back of the device towards north such that I'm currently at 0 degrees, then rotate it clockwise (yaw) a full 360 degrees, I'm now at -20 degrees. Counterclockwise rotations add 20 degrees. This pattern repeats itself such that rotating 720 degrees from 0 now yields -40 degrees and so on. Also, even if I don't necessarily do these clear rotations, but instead move the phone chaotically (spinning, shaking, etc), but end up in the same spot where I was initially, I can't even predict what value it will show.
2. The other problem is what I think is called gyro drift. If I don't move the device at all, I can clearly see how the value slowly changes over time, by let's say 0.1 degrees every few seconds, sometimes in one direction, sometimes the other, until a certain point where it decides to stop.

The problem is, I don't have the mathematical background to know how to account for these changes. It's especially problematic that I can't seem to compute the rotation matrix from yaw/pitch/roll from deviceMotion.attitude. I tried:

```
float w = motion.attitude.yaw;
float v = motion.attitude.pitch;
float u = motion.attitude.roll;
r.m11 = cos(v) * cos(w);
r.m12 = sin(u) * sin(v) * cos(w) - cos(u) * sin(w);
r.m13 = sin(u) * sin(w) + cos(u) * sin(v) * cos(w);
r.m21 = cos(v) * sin(w);
r.m22 = cos(u) * cos(w) + sin(u) * sin(v) * sin(w);
r.m23 = cos(u) * sin(v) * sin(w) - sin(u) * cos(w);
r.m31 = -sin(v);
r.m32 = sin(u) * cos(v);
r.m33 = cos(u) * cos(v);
```

I've tried every Tait–Bryan combination (u-v-w, u-w-v, v-u-w, v-w-u, w-v-u, w-u-v), some of them came close, but still not close enough.

From my observations, it seems like the magneticHeading from CLLocationManager is much more accurate than computed heading from CMMotionManager, but again, even if I got the correct angle, I don't know where should I start to get the equivalent angle in a different coordinate system reference frame. Any help would be greatly appreciated.